# cannot import IP, UDP from pinject

Tags: python

Добрый вечер. Подключил к своему скрипту модуль pinject

```
from pinject import IP, UDP
```

Запускаю скрипт, ошибка:

```
File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
from pinject import IP, UDP
ImportError: cannot import name IP
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего, вы установили модуль `pinject` с помощью `pip`. Судя по всему, `pip` устанавливает из своего репозитория [другой модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pinject) с таким названием:

```
$ pip search pinject
pinject     - A pythonic dependency injection library
```

А вам требуется модуль **`Pinject`, Raw Packet Injection tool** (судя по импортируемым классам `IP` и `UDP`). Его можно скачать с github-репозитория [*OffensivePython*](https://github.com/OffensivePython/Pinject) и разместить в той же директории, где находится ваш скрипт. Тогда вышеупомянутые классы успешно импортируются.

Comment: Скачал с репозитория, закинул в папку со скриптом. А дальше? Как его установить?

Comment: а удалили тот, который установили до этого? (если, конечно, так и было, как я предположил) Если скачанный модуль (`pinject.py`) находится там же, где и скрипт, то больше ничего делать не нужно.